# Topological invariance analogy of smooth invariance.

Tags: general-topology

> **Problem:** Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and
>   $f:U\rightarrow S$ a homeomorphism of $U$ onto $S$ in the induced topology.  Is $S$  open in 
>   $\mathbb{R}^n$?

How would I prove this? may I have hints? Does it even hold? as I'm unable to find a counterexample.

Comment: Do you mean hom**e**omorphism, rather than homomorphism?

Comment: @Reveillark indeed

Comment: Also, is the homeomorphism onto $S$? That is, do we have $S=f[U]$?

Comment: yeah @Reveillark

Comment: Just for the records, $S$ is open by the following theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain, I am thinking about an elementary solution (using only topology).

Comment: @MatheusManzatto the hypothesis of the the link you posted and the hypothesis of the problem I mentioned are quite different. For instancer, I did not assume that $S=\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: $f:U\to S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f(U) = S$ therefore $S$ is open.

Comment: @MatheusManzatto I'd be thrilled to be wrong, but there might not be an elementary argument, as it so often happens with invariance of domain, Brouwer, and friends.

Comment: @Reveillark I agree with you. Most likely I made an unfortunate comment. I remember that when I attended the metrics space course I tried to prove it, I failed miserably, I only learned to how prove this result years later in algebraic topology classes.